# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Project.Models.Artist' to 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Here is my code:

**ArtistAlbums.cshtml**

```
@page
@using Project.Models
@model Project.Pages.ArtistAlbumsModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<div class="row">
    <h1 class="display-2">Albums by @Model.Artist</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Album ID</th>
                <th>Album title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (Album album in Model.Albums)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@album.AlbumId</td>
                    <td>@album.Title</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p>Enter a name for a new album:&nbsp;</p>
    <form method="POST">
        <div><input asp-for="Album.Title" /></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="/Artists">Back to list</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
</div>
```

**ArtistAlbums.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Project.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Project.Pages
{
    public class ArtistAlbumsModel : PageModel
    {
        private Chinook db;

        public ArtistAlbumsModel(Chinook injectedContext)
        {
            db = injectedContext;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public void OnGetAsync(int id, int ArtistId)
        {
            ViewData["Title"] = "Chinook Web Site - Albums";
            Albums = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Artist).Where(a => a.ArtistId == id);
            // This works fine
            // Artist = "Placeholder artist"; 
            Artist = db.Albums.First(x => x.ArtistId == id);
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Album Album { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
public string Artist{ get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnPost(int id)
        {
            Album.ArtistId = id;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Albums.Add(Album);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToPage("/Albums/ArtistAlbums", new {id = id });
            }
            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult DeleteAlbum(int AlbumId, int id)
        {
            var track = db.Albums.Find(AlbumId);

            if (track == null) return Page();

            db.Albums.Remove(track);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToPage("/Albums/ArtistAlbums", new {id = id });
        }
    }
}
```

The hard-coded 'Placeholder artist' works just fine, but when I try to pull the artist name from the DB as above, I get

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Project.Models.Artist' to 'string'

I tried adding `.ToString()` wherever it seemed like it might fit, but that either didn't build or made the page actually display "Albums by Project.Models.Album".

Any help please? TIA.

Comment: `Artist = db.Albums.First(x => x.ArtistId == id).Name;`

Comment: Ah, it seems you were very close there! Apparently what's needed is `Artist = db.Artists.First(x => x.ArtistId == id).Name;`, I think. Thank you!!